# Use a method multiple times with different parameters efficiently

Tags: c#, methods

So i've got an API written in PHP to update/add/remove entries in my database, i use C# to communicate with PHP (post data). But i don't want to have multiple methods with basically almost the same code that does something different.

This is how my methods look like to update a member in my database:

```
      public static bool UpdateMember(string name, string lastname, string ismanager, string birthday, string positionID, string memberID)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            NameValueCollection PostLoginData = new NameValueCollection()
            {
                {"update_Member","1" },
                {"Name", name },
                {"LastName", lastname },
                {"isManager", ismanager },
                {"Birthday", birthday },
                {"PositionID", positionID},
                {"MemberID", memberID }
            };
            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues($"{Domain}API.php", PostLoginData));
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
            if (json.result == "success")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how my method looks like to add an position to my database:

```
     public static bool UploadPosition(string PosName)
    {

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            NameValueCollection postPlatformData = new NameValueCollection()
            {
                {"add_Position","1" },
                {"PosName",PosName }

            };
            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues($"{Domain}/API.php", postPlatformData));
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
            if (json.result == "success")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see the only thing that is different is my NameValueCollection. 
I could have a namevaluecollection in the parameter of the method, but i'm asking if there is a better way to solve this problem, so my question is:

is there a way to have only one method instead of multiple that basically do the same thing, efficiently?

Comment: Take all the duplicated code and put it in a method that takes in a `NameValueCollection`, then call that method from your existing methods with the respective collections. Any time you start writing duplicated code, you should ask yourself if it can be extracted into a reusable method.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide that into two level. On the lower level have a method, that knows how to send a `NameValueCollection`.

```
public static bool Update(NameValueCollection nameValueCollection)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues($"{Domain}/API.php", nameValueCollection));
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
        if (json.result == "success")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

On the higher level have methods, that know how to build a specific `NameValueCollection` and call the lower level method to actually send them.

```
public static bool UpdateMember(string name, string lastname, string ismanager, string birthday, string positionID, string memberID)
{
    return Update(new NameValueCollection()
    {
        {"update_Member","1" },
        {"Name", name },
        {"LastName", lastname },
        {"isManager", ismanager },
        {"Birthday", birthday },
        {"PositionID", positionID},
        {"MemberID", memberID }
    });
}

public static bool UploadPosition(string PosName)
{
    return Update(new NameValueCollection()
    {
        {"add_Position","1" },
        {"PosName",PosName }
    });
}
```